# ¿Se puede crear una subcarpeta dentro de la carpeta raw?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica con canciones alojadas en el raw, pero quiero saber si se puede añadir una sub carpeta dentro del raw para poner otras canciones. Porque quiero hacer diferentes activity que contengan diferentes canciones en cada una de ellas.
En cada activity utilizo un listview para reproducirlo desde ahi.

este es el codigo que estoy utilizando.

```
    ListView listaCanciones;
List<String> list;
ListAdapter adapter;

MediaPlayer mp;

int posicion = 0;
Button pause, btn_repetir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_album2);

    pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
    listaCanciones = findViewById(R.id.list);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        list.add(fields[i].getName());
    }


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item_album2, list);
    listaCanciones.setAdapter(adapter);

    listaCanciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(mp != null ){
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }



            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(album2.this, resID);
            mp.start();
            pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

public void pause(View view){
    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
        pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pausa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        mp.start();
        pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

como veran al momento de llamar a la carpeta raw en mi listview van todas las canciones que estan alojadas en ellas, yo quiero poner diferentes canciones en cada listview de cada activity.
Les agradeceria mucho una ayuda.
desde ya muchas gracias...

[image]

Comment: Quizá se pueda, recurriendo a cierto procedimiento complicado que pasa por hacerlo vía gradle primero  ([ver esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4930398/5587982)). Quizá sea más simple crear los subdirectorios en `assets`. Ten en cuenta que para acceder necesitarás usar la clase `R`. Para más detalles, ver las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15508160/5587982).

Comment: Gracias por comentar,  voy a probar los dos métodos para ver si me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Se puede crear una subcarpeta dentro de la carpeta raw?

**NO, no se pueden crear subfolders ya que no es permitido por la estructura definida para este directorio (incluso tratar de crear prográmaticamente un directorio dentro de /raw la razón es simplemente que directorios como `/raw` y `/assets` son de solo lectura, por lo tanto solo puedes leer información pero no escribir).**

Si deseas usar subdirectorios, como opción puedes usar el directorio `/assets/` y ahí crear subdirectorios y almacenar tus archivos de audio, por ejemplo:

```
main/
├── asssets/
    ├── audio1.mp3
    ├── audio2.mp3
    └── audio3.mp3
    ├── otro/
        ├── otroaudio1.mp3
        └── otroaudio2.mp3
```

Para acceder a los audios del subdirectorio realizas lo siguiente, definiendo subdirectorio y nombre de archivo:

```
   AssetFileDescriptor afd1 = getAssets().openFd("otro/otroaudio1.mp3");       
   ...
   AssetFileDescriptor afd2 = getAssets().openFd("otro/otroaudio2.mp3");
```

Este sería un ejemplo para reproducir un audio que se encuentra dentro de un subdirectorio del directorio `/raw` del proyecto :

```
   try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("otro/otroaudio1.mp3");
        final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                //Ready to play!
                player.start();
            }
        });
        //Prepare player
        player.prepare();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Realice lo que me recomendaste y funciona una parte, al entrar en ese activity reproduce automaticamente la canciones. pero yo necesito que estè en mi listview y desde ahi poder controlarlo mediante el boton play_pause.

Comment: En el codigo principal subi una imagen de como esta el codigo con assets

Comment: Hola Yonathan, te sugiero que crees otra pregunta donde ahora expongas el problema de leer varios archivos y agrega el código que ahora se necesite, me parece que se debe a que tienes definido un nombre de archivo fijo, recuerda agregar como texto el código para que sea legible para todos.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda.. volvi a reformular mi pregunta espero que se entienda..

Comment: @YonathanCulzoni te comentaba que crearas otra pregunta pero ahora con el problema de los metodos para reproducción/pausa , de otra forma esta respuesta no será válida ni tendrá que ver con la pregunta original, por eso te sugerí crear otra pregunta y hacer referencia a esta.